# Propriedade Name não funciona usando o Razor HiddenFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou criando vários campos dinamicamente usando Asp.net Razor e para isso estou passando o índice para uma partial view e setando a propriedade name de cada field. Tudo está funcionando bem com todos os campos exceto Id e PessoaId que são construídos usando @Html.HiddenFor e ficam ocultos.

Se eu setar a propriedade name conforme o exemplo abaixo e passar o índice, funciona:

```
<label asp-for="Contato" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
```

Se eu tentar usar o Razor @Html.HiddenFor, a propriedade name não está recebendo o índice corretamente (Não sei se é pelo fato de eu estar usando @name) e os fields são setados com valor 0:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "hid-id", @name = "PessoasContatosViewModel["+@indice+"].Id"})
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoaId, new { @class = "hid-pessoaId", @name = "PessoasContatosViewModel["+@indice+"].PessoaId"})
```

O que está dando errado? Existe alguma maneira de setar o name desses dois fields para o índice ser passado corretamente.

Código completo da view:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaContatoViewModel
@{
    int indice = ViewBag.indice;
}

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "hid-id", @name = "PessoasContatosViewModel["+@indice+"].Id"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoaId, new { @class = "hid-pessoaId", @name = "PessoasContatosViewModel["+@indice+"].PessoaId"})
            <label asp-for="ContatoTipoId" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
            <select asp-for="ContatoTipoId" asp-items="Model.ContatosTipos" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].ContatoTipoId" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ContatoTipoId" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].ContatoTipoId" class="text-danger sel-contatoTipo"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="Contato" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Contato" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Contato" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Contato" class="text-danger txt-contato"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label asp-for="Detalhes" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>
            <textarea asp-for="Detalhes" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Detalhes" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Detalhes" class="text-danger txt-detalhes"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="ContatoPrincipal" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />
                <label asp-for="ContatoPrincipal" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" data-id="@Model.Id." style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```js
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Id" />
```

Comment: Olá Victor Laio. Essa partial está certa assim mesmo, os demais campos funcional mesmo eu não passando o Índice Ex:  <input type="text" asp-for="Contato" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />.... Eles funcionam pq possuim a propriedade name onde o índice é passado. O problema do Id e PessoaId é que a mesma forma não está funcionando se eu passar o name assim:  @name = "PessoasContatosViewModel["+@indice+"].Id"

Comment: Aaa entendi entao sua dúvida! Já tentou criar o hidden input manualmente então?`<input type="hidden" name="@model.Id"/>`

Comment: Funcionou!!!!!! Obrigado Victor!! A resolução foi: <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" name="PessoasContatosViewModel[@indice].Id" />. Comenta no post principal pata eu definir como resposta : )

Comment: Feito! Pode setar como resposta!